# Highchart pie graph not displaying in r

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

This may have been answered with java but I'm trying to do this in r. I've left out most of the code because there is quite a lot.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("xxx"),
    fluidRow(
      #...
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
        highchartOutput("column")     
      ),
      column(3,
        highchartOutput("pie.selected")
      ),
      column(3,
        highchartOutput("pie.prior")
      )
    )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
#...
  output$pie.selected <- renderHighchart({
    pie.selected <- highchart() %>% 
      hc_add_series(name = "Current Valuation",
                    type = "pie",
                    tooltip = list(
                      valueDecimals = 1,
                      valueSuffix = " %"
                    ),
                    data = list(
                    list(y = 100*pd.selected/ult.selected,
                         name = "Paid",
                         color = colors$Emrl
                    ),
                    list(y = 100*co.selected/ult.selected, 
                         name = "Case Outstanding",
                         color = colors$Ruby
                    ),
                    list(y = 100*ibnr.selected/ult.selected, 
                         name = "IBNR",
                         color = colors$Saph
                    )
      )
    ) 
  })
#...
})
```

I have never made a pie graph before and figured it would be done the done way as a bar or column graph, but I guess I am missing something. I followed this: http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts.html (first example with pie chart) but it simply isn't loaded when I run the app. If I simply run the server code in an r script it works great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the name of the input can't have a period in it with Highchart.